# Angular 2 : No NgModule metadata found

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I'm brand new to Angular 2 and attempting to follow along with a video tutorial I found. Despite following all of the steps, Angular just won't work; I get the following error:

```
compiler.umd.js:13854 Uncaught Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'App'.
```

and the component doesn't load at all.

Here are my files:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "retain",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "webpack --config webpack.spec.ts --progress --color && karma start",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --colors --progress --display-error-details --display-cached --port 3000  --content-base src"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "lodash": "4.16.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.33",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.35",
    "@types/node": "6.0.39",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "2.2.4",
    "css-loader": "0.23.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "karma": "1.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "2.0.4",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.4",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
    "typescript": "2.0.2",
    "webpack": "1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.14.1"
  }
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=UTF-8>
    <title>Retain</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.1.1/normalize.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/flexboxgrid/6.3.0/flexboxgrid.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="global.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <base href="/">
  </head>
  <body>

    <app>
      ... before angular loads.
    </app>

    <script src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="main.bundle.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

main.ts:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module'; 

import { App } from './app/app';

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(App);

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

app.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h3>
        Yo, world!
      </h3>
    </div>
    `
})

export class App {}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; 
import { App } from './app'; 

@NgModule({ 
  imports: [BrowserModule], 
  declarations: [App], 
  bootstrap: [App] 
}) 

export class AppModule{};
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: where is `app.module.ts` file?

Comment: Apologies, I've added that now.

Comment: are you using angular-cli?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The problem is in your `main.ts` file.

```
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(App);
```

You are trying to bootstrap `App`, which is not a real module.
Delete these two lines and replace with the following line:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

and it will fix your error.

Comment: This also won't work (note that I have AppModule):  `const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);`  Only after dropping the `const` and combining the statements does it work.

Comment: What the hell, not declaring `const platform` separately indeed solved the problem here too. Why does that matter? it is (SHOULD syntactically be 100% the same... And why is the error reporting from `Angular/cli` so extremely bad regarding this :/

Answer (score 103):

I had this error even though I had everything that the answers above suggested in place. A simple edit in the `app.module.ts` file ( like delete a bracket and put it back) did the trick.

Comment: The same worked for me after upgrading to angular 5.1.0 today

Comment: I just open the app.module.ts file, hit save, and then it works for me. Angular 5.0.0 and angular cli 1.6.3 - using vs code.

Comment: I am  using angular5.1.0. After npm start was stucked with ngModule issue. but this trick works! Thanks

Comment: This solves `ng serve` errors but still `ng build` gives the same error and doesn't create the dist folder

Comment: for ng build, you can try `ng build --prod --aot=false`

Comment: This is not a viable solution for projects with a continuous integration process. In my case, jenkins detects the build is broken. I can't tell jenkins to go in and change a file then restore it and save it...

Comment: angular one love

Comment: Yes, Its Working. But How?? Why?

Comment: what the hell... this works for mee  too :)))))))))))))))))

Comment: This fix worked for me. My guess it is happened because I rebuilt a shared module by hand but Angular failed to detect it and rebuild the app the module was included in. Editing any file in the app forces a rebuild which fixes it.

Answer (score 32):

Try to remove node_modules
`rm -rf node_modules` and package-lock.json `rm -rf package-lock.json`,
after that run `npm install`.

Comment: For me too! I was afraid I had to migrate from Http to HttpClient as I read in any post (I know I have to do it, but right now it would kill me), but this solution worked fine.

Comment: I upgraded from angular-cli 1.6.0 to 1.6.4. Your answer did the trick for me. Thx

Comment: Didn't have to delete package-lock.json, just reinstalling node_modules did the trick for me

Comment: I had this exact issue after having updated to Angular 9.1 - Thanks a lot, this solved it

Answer (score 26):

After upgrading to Angular 6, I encountered the `"ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'."` with the angular-bootstrap-md package, which requires a tsconfig.json "include" as follows:

`"include": ["node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/**/*.ts",  "src/**/*.ts"],`

After days of troubleshooting and hair pulling, the solution was to arrange the list so that the app.module.ts was located first, under "src/**/*.ts".  An Angular bug, perhaps?

`"include": ["src/**/*.ts","node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/**/*.ts" ],`

I genuinely hope this helps somebody, as I tried everything in this posting and nothing helped.  After this change, everything compiles and works beautifully, as expected.

Comment: Thank your very very very much. Maybe bugs of angular-bootstrap-md?

Comment: Top answer for me. This is not the first time that Angular Bootstrap MD messed things up for me.

Comment: I do not have #$%$$ idea how u could identify that was the issue... but thanks god u did it...was getting crazy here.

Comment: This will henceforth be known as a Great Finding! You, fellow coder, are a Finder.

Comment: I faced this issue while upgrading from angular 5.x to angular 7.x and this solution worked fine for me.

Comment: Smooth. Worked with angular-autosize too in Win10 with 7.1.4 Angular meanwhile in mac worked fine.
Before: "include": ["../node_modules/angular-autosize/**/*.ts", "**/*.ts"].
After: "include": [ "**/*.ts", "../node_modules/angular-autosize/**/*.ts"

Answer (score 9):

The issue is fixed only when re installed angular/cli manually.
Follow following steps.
(run all command under Angular project dir)

1)Remove webpack by using following command.

```
npm remove webpack
```

2)Install cli by using following command.

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

after successfully test app, it will work :)

if not then follow below steps.

1) Delete node_module folder.

2) Clear cache by using following command.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

3) Install node packages by using following command.

```
npm install
```

4)Install angular@cli by using following command.

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

Note :if failed,try again :)

5) Celebrate :)

Comment: Voted up.  However, if you're lazy like me, I was able to get past the problem by only deleting the node_module folder, and running npm install.

Answer (score 7):

> I would recommend restarting the application. Most of the cases editor won't be able to detect the changes in the lazy loaded module.

Comment: Thanks, time saviour!

Answer (score 6):

Late answer, but this might help someone. I got the same error, tried out all the previously mentioned suggestions, banged my head against the wall, but nothing worked.

On careful observation, I noticed the following in app.module.ts:

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpClientModule,, // Redundant comma 
  CoreModule
];
```

So I banged my head some more. The extra comma, very innocently higlighted, by WebStorm, as a mild warning, wreaked havoc by inserting an empty slot in the Array. Watchout fot the [elision](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas#Arrays) trap ;)

Answer (score 3):

There are more reasons for getting this error. This means your application failed to build as expected.

**Check for the following..**

- Check whether the node_modules version are not changed, this is the
  primary reason.
- If you are moving from Some other Build tool to webpack, For example
  Systemjs to Webpack, If some of your dependencies are not modular in
  nature you may get this error, check for that too.
- Check for Obsolete features of the framework, Ex: **"HTTP_PROVIDERS"**
  in angular 2 and remove them.
- If you are upgrading, then make sure you are following the current
  syntax of the Framework, for Ex: **routing** syntax has been changed in
  Angular2..
- Check the Bootstraping process and make sure you are loading the
  correct Module.

Comment: "Check whether the node_modules version are not changed, this is the primary reason" - please elaborate  
"If some of your dependencies are not modular in nature" - could you also elaborate?

Comment: The issue was the builder using webpack `"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server"`,

Answer (score 2):

In your `main.ts`, you are bootstrapping both your AppModule *and* your App. It should just be the AppModule, which then bootstraps the App.

If you compare your main.ts to the docs you'll see the difference - just remove all references to App from main.ts

Answer (score 2):

With Angular 5, I solved a similar problem by ugrading to `@angular/cli` 1.6.1 from 1.5.5:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "1.6.1"
}
```

During `ng serve` the error I got was:

```
ERROR in Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.
    at NgModuleResolver.resolve (/path/to/project/app/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:20247:23)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and couldn't solve it after reading all the above answers. Then I noticed that an extra comma in declarations was creating a problem. Removed it, problem solved.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        PagesRoutingModule,
        ThemeModule,
        DashboardModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        ...PAGES_COMPONENTS,
        **,**
    ],
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope it can help. In my case, I work with lazy-load module and I found this mistake lead to 
`ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'MyModule'.`

`in app-routing.module.ts`
`{ path: 'mc3', loadChildren: 'app/module/my/my.module#MxModule' },`

If I run `ng serve --aot` chrome dev tool can tell me `Error: Cannot find 'Mc4Module' in 'app/module/mc3/mc3.module'`

Answer (score 2):

If you are having this issue in Angular 8 or Angular 9 (like I was), after:

- Clearing your npm cache
- reinstalling all node_modules
- checking your "include" and "files" tsconfig setting etc

and you're still having issues, and you are **Lazy Loading Modules** check your `angularCompilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.app.json`, and make sure that **"strictMetadataEmit"** is set to **false** or is removed.

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "preserveWhitespaces": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    // "strictMetadataEmit": true <-- remove this setting or set to false
},
```

The setting is to help library creators which should never have lazy loaded modules built in. I had previously (using Angular 7) set all "strict" options to true...

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when i cloned from a git repository and I had it resolved when I created a new project and re-inserted the src folder from the old project.

The src folder is the only folder needed when deploying your angular application but you must reconfigure the dev environment, using this solution.

Answer (score 1):

you need to enable the ngModel directive. This is done by adding the FormsModule to the imports[] array in the AppModule.

You then also need to add the import from @angular/forms in the app.module.ts file:
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

Comment: it fixed the issue, but why?@Abdullah Sheikh

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution.

1. Remove webpack by using following command.

```
npm remove webpack
```

2. Install cli by using following command.

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

after successfully test app, it will work :)

If not then follow below steps:

1. Delete node_module folder.
2. Clear cache by using following command.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

3. Install node packages by using following command.

```
npm install
```

4. Install angular@cli by using following command.

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

Note: If failed, try step 4 again. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue with a lazy-loaded module. It turns out that the name of the module was incorrect.

Check the names of all your modules for possible typos.

Answer (score 0):

We've faced this issue on Angular Cli 1.7.4 at times. Initially we've got

```
Cannot read property 'config' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
```

And fixing this lead to the above issue.

We've removed package-lock.json

```
npm remove webpack

npm cache clean --force
```

You can also remove your node_modules folder. And then clean the cache.
re-installed angular cli:

```
npm install @angular/cli@1.7.4
```

And then you can do npm install again, just to make sure if everything is installed.

Then run

```
npm ls --depth 0
```

To make sure if all your node_modules are in sync with each other. If there are any dependency mismatching, this is the opportunity for us to figure out.

Finally run npm start/ng serve. it should fix everything.

This is out cheat code that we'll follow if we run into any issues with cli, before we dig deeper. 95% of times it fixes all the issues.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to upgrade my angular 6 project using `ng update` after that the entire universe collapse.

I was trying to update my project using this commands:

- ng update @angular/cli
- ng update @angular/core
- ng update @angular/material

And then I found a problem with rxjs package and I run also this command.
- npm install --save rxjs

And then I get the error

> **No NgModule metadata found**

I solve this by deleting my **node_modules** folder in the project root
and then I run:

- npm install

That's is, all works nice.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the cause of this problem in my case, was that I've combined my Angular app with a node.js application in the same source tree, and in the root `tsconfig.json` I had:

`"files": [
    "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts"
  ]`

I changed this to

`"compilerOptions": {
  "types": ["node"]
 }`

And then to prevent node types being uses in your angular app, add this to `tsconfig.app.json`:

`"compilerOptions": {
  "types": []
 }`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but none of all those solutions worked for me. After further investigation, I found out that an undesired import was in one of my component.

I use `setTimeout` function in app.component but for any reason Visual Studio added `import { setTimeout } from 'timer';` where it was not needed. Removing this line fixed the issue.

So remember to check your imports before going further. Hope it may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem twice now. Both times were problems with how I was implementing my lazy loading. In my routing module I had my routes defines as:

```
  {
    path: "game",
    loadChildren: () => import("./game/game.module").then(m => {m.GameModule})
  }
```

But this is wrong. After the second => you don't need curly braces. it should look like this:

```
  {
    path: "game",
    loadChildren: () => import("./game/game.module").then(m => m.GameModule)
 }
```

Comment: This is good to know that, that particular mistake will cause that error which is strange. Might be helpful for some.

Comment: this error is incredible. I spent an hour trying to fix this and it was just a bracket issue.

Comment: loadChildren: () => import("./game/game.module").then(m => m.GameModule)

is equivalent to 
```
loadChildren: () => import("./game/game.module").then(m => {return m.GameModule})
```
First style is a shortcut. When function has only one line of code and if it is a return statement then you can omit {} and 'return' keyword.
If function has multiple lines of code, you need to put it in {}

Comment: I am a bit slow on ES6: The 1st version just (uselessly) ‘states’ the particular value, only in the 2nd version the function returns it. right?

Comment: Yes,  when you use curly braces there is no implicit return. Assumably one could use curly braces and a return statement and it would still work.

Answer (score 0):

This error says necessary data for your module can't be found.
In my case i missed an **@** symbol in start of NgModule.

Correct NgModule definition:

```
 @NgModule ({ 
    ... 
 })
 export class AppModule {

 }
```

My case (Wrong case) :

```
NgModule ({ // => this line must starts with @
   ... 
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I resolved it by closing the editor i.e. `Visual Studio Code`, started it again, run `ng serve` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had defined a couple of (private) static methods in one of my components and was using them in the same component.

Comment: AFAIK: This exact issue can be fixed by setting strictMetadataEmit to false. Or commenting the classes with `// @dynamic`

Answer (score 0):

If Nothing else works try following

```
if (environment.production) {
        // there is no need of this if block, angular internally creates following code structure when it sees --prod
        // but at the time of writting this code, else block was not working in the production mode and NgModule metadata
        // not found for AppModule error was coming at run time, added follow code to fix that, it can be removed probably 
        // when angular is upgraded to latest version or if it start working automatically. :)
        // we could also avoid else block but building without --prod saves time in building app locally.
        platformBrowser(extraProviders).bootstrapModuleFactory(<any>AppModuleNgFactory);
    } else {
        platformBrowserDynamic(extraProviders).bootstrapModule(AppModule);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I had created a method named `hasOwnProperty(obj, prop)` in a Angular component.
The solution for me was deleting or renaming the method

Answer (score -1):

I'll give you few suggestions.Remove all these as mentioned below

```
1)<script src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>(index.html)  //<<<===not sure as Angular2.0 final version doesn't require this.

2)platform.bootstrapModule(App); (main.ts)

3)import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; (app.ts)
```

Answer (score -1):

Using ngcWebpack Plugin I got this error when not specifying a mainPath or entryModule.