# Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem with an Angular 2 app that I am building. I have been exercising my copy/paste skills from various locations, and have eliminated all of the build errors, but when I launch it in the browser I have an error in the browser. I have looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685179/angular-2-no-ngmodule-metadata-found) but it hasn't solved my problem.

My `AppModule` looks like this:

```
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ROUTES } from './app.routes';
import { HomeComponent } from '../index';

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ AppModule ],
  declarations: [
    AppModule,
     HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true })
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I'm bootstrapping like this:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './index';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

But in my browser, I get this error:

> ng_module_resolver.js:34 Uncaught Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.

How do I solve this?

## Update

My code looks like this now, but still generate an error:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ROUTES } from './app.routes';
import { HomeComponent } from '../index';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule( {
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot( ROUTES, { useHash: true } )
    ],
    declarations: [
        HomeComponent,
        AppComponent
    ]
} )
export class AppModule {
}
```

And bootstraping:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './index';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppComponent);
```

This is the error I'm getting now:

> Uncaught Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppComponent'

Is this an error with `AppComponent`, or the bootstrapping, or the module declaration and metadata? The documentation is vague.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three mistakes at least in your code.

**First** - you are bootstraping component, this is wrong - you should bootstrap module, in your case `AppModule` and in `AppModule` you should choose the component that is going to be bootstrapped.

**Second** - you are specifying `AppModule` as a component that's going to be bootstrapped:

```
bootstrap: [ AppModule ]
```

You can't bootstrap module, you can bootstrap component, for example `HomeComponent`. From what I can see, that's the only component you have.

**Third** - you are adding `AppModule` to its declarations:

```
declarations: [
  AppModule,
  HomeComponent
]
```

You simply cannot do this, you should only add components, directives and pipes to module's declarations and even if you could declare modules, why would you declare `AppModule` inside itself? Try this code:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true })
  ],
  declarations: [ HomeComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ HomeComponent ]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

And then bootstrap `AppModule`:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: But the post I referenced in my post has an answer that is marked as correct. It bootstraps the app using a module. However, the Angular docs indicate that the bootstrap takes an array of components as a value. Confusing.

Comment: @serlingpa You do bootstrap a module, but in that module, you specify the component that is going to be bootstraped - that is your root component, the first component that will be displayed when you start your app.

Comment: Hooray! Thank you Stefan. My app is now bootstrapping the module and launching the component as expected. Nice one.

Comment: @serlingpa You're welcome, I edited my answer so it is complete now. I also strongly suggest that you complete official Angular 2 Tour of Heroes tutorial, it will help you understand a lot of things that are so confusing right now: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/

Comment: To be honest Stefan, I think I've got a good grip of pre-module Angular 2. The NgModule stuff has just made me wobble a little!

Comment: This answer is confusing because the **First** step "you are bootstraping component, this is wrong - you should bootstrap module" directly contradicts the **Second** step "You can't bootstrap module, you can bootstrap component."  Can anybody clarify?