# Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'

Tags: angular

I have problem in angular 2 that i am tried. I check that some of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249425/error-no-ngmodule-metadata-found-for-appmodule) like my problem but that does not solve my problem.

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports:[
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    declarations:[
        AppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap:[
        AppComponent
    ]
});

export class AppModule { }
```

main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule }              from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

I am getting this error

> Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'

Comment: I dont find any issue with your shared code. Can you upload your code on github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have separated NgModule and AppModule in two parts with semicolon.

The `NgModule` is a decorator for `AppModule`.Don't separate them in parts.

```
@NgModule({
    imports:[
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    declarations:[
        AppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap:[
        AppComponent
    ]
})
// });     // here is the problem.
export class AppModule { }
```