# No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule' in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I am developing an Angular application with ASP.NET Core 2

I have upgraded it to Angular 5 and tried to publish it on Azure. The problem is that I get the error:

```
No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'
```

when I try to run the app in "Production" setting, but not all the time if I try to run it in "Development".

I know I am missing something, but I do not know what it is.

I followed the template from https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal

So I have:

```
app.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import { UserService } from "../../services/Authorization/user.service";

import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { ServerBusyService } from "../../services/serverBusy.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    loginSubscription: Subscription;
    logoutSubscription: Subscription;

    constructor(/*private translate: TranslateService,*/
        public userService: UserService,
        public serverBusyService: ServerBusyService
    ) {
        // this language will be used as a fallback when a translation isn't found in the current language
        //translate.setDefaultLang('en');

        // the lang to use, if the lang isn't available, it will use the current loader to get them
        //translate.use('en');

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.userService.isLoggedIn && !this.userService.email) {
            this.userService.getLogeddInUserInfo().subscribe((x: any) => x);
        }
    }

    switchLanguage(language: string) {
        //this.translate.use(language);
    }

    onDeactivate() {
        document.body.scrollTop = 0;
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
}
```

app.module.browser.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleShared } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { ORIGIN_URL } from "./constansts/baseurl.constants";
import { UserService } from "./services/Authorization/user.service";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { BrowserPrebootModule } from 'preboot/browser';

export function getOriginUrl() {
    return window.location.origin;
}


@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    imports: [
        BrowserPrebootModule.replayEvents(),
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AppModuleShared
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            // We need this for our Http calls since they'll be using an ORIGIN_URL provided in main.server
            // (Also remember the Server requires Absolute URLs)
            provide: ORIGIN_URL,
            useFactory: (getOriginUrl)
        },
        {
            provide: 'BASE_URL',
            useFactory: getBaseUrl
        },
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}

export function getBaseUrl() {
    return document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href;
}
```

app.module.server.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { AppModuleShared } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    imports: [
        ServerModule,
        AppModuleShared
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, PlatformRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';
import { UserComponent } from "./components/user/list.user.component";
import { ListErrorComponent } from "./components/error/error.component";

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader, TranslateService, TranslateFakeLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

import { ORIGIN_URL } from "./constansts/baseurl.constants";
import { LoginFormComponent } from "./account/login-form/login-form.component";
import { RegistrationFormComponent } from "./account/registration-form/registration-form.component";
import { UserService } from "./services/Authorization/user.service";
import { ConfigService } from "./shared/utils/config.service";

import { MessageService } from "./services/Authorization/message.service";
import { AuthGuard } from "./account/auth.guard";
import { ServerBusyService } from "./services/serverBusy.service";
import { CoolStorageModule } from "angular2-cool-storage";
import { TranslateStore } from "@ngx-translate/core/src/translate.store";


export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient, baseHref: any) {
    if (baseHref === null && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        baseHref = window.location.origin;
    }
    //return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, `${baseHref}/assets/i18n/`, '.json');
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        .
        .
        .
    ],
    imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        CommonModule,
        CoolStorageModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'home-help', component: HelpHomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
            { path: 'steps', component: StepsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
            { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
            { path: 'dashboard-help', component: HelpDashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },

            { path: 'login', component: LoginFormComponent },
            { path: 'register', component: RegistrationFormComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },

            { path: 'user', component: UserComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
            { path: 'add-user', component: AddUserComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
            { path: 'add-user-help', component: HelpAddUserComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }, 
            { path: 'view-user/:username', component: ViewUserComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },



            { path: 'add-afmStatementIdentifiers', component: AddAfmStatementIdentifiersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },

            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ]),
        BrowserModule,
        //TranslateModule.forRoot({
        //    loader: {
        //        provide: TranslateLoader,
        //        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        //        deps: [HttpClient, [ORIGIN_URL]]
        //    }
        //})
    ],
    providers: [
        PlatformRef,
        ConfigService,
        CompanyService,

        MessageService,
        AuthGuard,
        ServerBusyService,
        UserService,
        //TranslateService,
        //TranslateStore 
    ]
})

export class AppModuleShared {
}
```

boot.browser.ts

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js';
import 'bootstrap';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module.browser';

if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
    module.hot.dispose(() => {
        // Before restarting the app, we create a new root element and dispose the old one
        const oldRootElem = document.querySelector('app');
        const newRootElem = document.createElement('app');
        oldRootElem!.parentNode!.insertBefore(newRootElem, oldRootElem);
        modulePromise.then(appModule => appModule.destroy());
    });
} else {
    enableProdMode();
}

// Note: @ng-tools/webpack looks for the following expression when performing production
// builds. Don't change how this line looks, otherwise you may break tree-shaking.
const modulePromise = platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

boot.server.ts

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { enableProdMode, ApplicationRef, NgZone, ValueProvider } from '@angular/core';
import { platformDynamicServer, PlatformState, INITIAL_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { createServerRenderer, RenderResult } from 'aspnet-prerendering';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module.server';


import { ORIGIN_URL } from './app/constansts/baseurl.constants';

enableProdMode();

export default createServerRenderer(params => {
    const providers = [
        { provide: INITIAL_CONFIG, useValue: { document: '<app></app>', url: params.url } },
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: params.baseUrl },
        { provide: 'BASE_URL', useValue: params.origin + params.baseUrl },
        { provide: ORIGIN_URL, useValue: params.origin }
    ];

    return platformDynamicServer(providers).bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(moduleRef => {
        const appRef: ApplicationRef = moduleRef.injector.get(ApplicationRef);
        const state = moduleRef.injector.get(PlatformState);
        const zone = moduleRef.injector.get(NgZone);

        return new Promise<RenderResult>((resolve, reject) => {
            zone.onError.subscribe((errorInfo: any) => reject(errorInfo));
            appRef.isStable.first(isStable => isStable).subscribe(() => {
                // Because 'onStable' fires before 'onError', we have to delay slightly before
                // completing the request in case there's an error to report
                setImmediate(() => {
                    resolve({
                        html: state.renderToString()
                    });
                    moduleRef.destroy();
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "SIGAD",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.4",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.2",
    "angular2-cool-storage": "^3.1.3",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.12",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.5",
    "html-loader": "0.5.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "ng2-datepicker-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "preboot": "^5.1.7",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "style-loader": "0.19.0",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "^2.6.1",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.20.0",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.4",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.9.0-rc.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.2",
    "chai": "4.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.6",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5"
  }
}
```

I am really out of ideas of what the problems might be

I read the post: [Angular 2 : No NgModule metadata found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685179/angular-2-no-ngmodule-metadata-found)

- I deleted node_modules folder and did npm install
- I moved to webpack a while ago so I do not think this is the problem
- I searched for "HTTP_PROVIDERS" in the solution and got results in "vendor.js" and "main-server.js", but not in my Angular code

Thank you!

P.S. The reason why I upgraded to Angular 5 is that when I had Angular 4 I could not publish to Azure because I was getting the error that webpack exited with error code 2 and I read on another post that people who upgraded to Angular 5 were not getting it anymore.

Comment: Disable SSR in your project. Current project configuration won't be able to do treeshaking while the SSR is enabled. The team is working on a new template to make it work. Take a look at this comment made by Steve Sanderson - https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1385#issuecomment-346647606

Comment: I changed <app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app> to <app>Loading...</app> with no changes...

Comment: Try editing boot.server.ts; change from: `const zone = moduleRef.injector.get(NgZone);` to `const zone: NgZone = moduleRef.injector.get(NgZone);`; see [here](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal/issues/460#issuecomment-354783181)