# Angular 5 AOT compilation throws an error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular2-aot

I am attempting to start my Angular5 application for the first time using AOT compilation and have the following error occur when I try this.

```
compiler.js:20242 Uncaught Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.
    at NgModuleResolver.resolve (compiler.js:20242)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15195)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34405)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34366)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:34260)
    at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:239)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:5567)
    at eval (main.ts:14)
    at Object../src/main.ts (main.bundle.js:269)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
```

This is when I run the following to start the application:

```
ng serve --aot true
```

When I start the application without the --aot true flag the application bootstraps correctly and works without error.

As this is my first attempt at AOT compilation I don't know where to start.

Here is my app.module file:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { LayoutModule } from './layout/layout.module';
import { RoutesModule } from './routes/routes.module';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';

import { PreLoaderService } from './core/preLoader/preLoader.service';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CoreModule,
    RoutesModule,
    LayoutModule
  ],
  providers: [
    PreLoaderService
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And my main.ts file:

```
import './polyfills.ts';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/';

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

My .tsconfig file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

And my angular-cli.json file

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.19-3",
    "name": "q2c-shell"
  },
  "apps": [{
    "root": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "assets": [
      "assets",
      "favicon.png"
    ],
    "index": "index.html",
    "main": "main.ts",
    "test": "test.ts",
    "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
    "prefix": "app",
    "mobile": false,
    "styles": [
      "styles.scss",
      "../node_modules/openlayers/css/ol.css",
      "../node_modules/loaders.css/loaders.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/js/tab.js",
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js",
      "../node_modules/openlayers/dist/ol.js",
      "../node_modules/proj4/dist/proj4.js",
      "../node_modules/web-animations-js/web-animations.min.js",
      "../node_modules/jsts/dist/jsts.min.js",
      "../node_modules/blob-util/dist/blob-util.min.js",
      "./assets/js/fontawesome-all.min.js",
      "./assets/js/fa-v4-shims.min.js"
    ],
    "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
    "environments": {
      "source": "environments/environment.ts",
      "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
      "bvt": "environments/environment.bvt.ts",
      "uat": "environments/environment.uat.ts",
      "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
  }],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone see why this error may be happening?
thanks

Comment: Can you post your `tsconfig.json` files (all of them, if you have more than one) and your `compiler-cli.json` (if you're using the CLI, which I assume you are)

Comment: @OscarPaz I believe the `compiler-cli` file doesn't exist, but `angular-cli` does !

Comment: Well, yes, that one. My mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 : No NgModule metadata found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685179/angular-2-no-ngmodule-metadata-found)

Comment: I have added both the tsconfig and angular-cli.json files to the original question

Comment: Tell me, when in `main.ts` you're importing `AppModule` from `./app`, you are importing it from an `index.ts` file that re-rexports it from `app.module.ts`?

Comment: what version of angularcli are you using?

Comment: "@angular/cli": "1.7.4",

Comment: Please, answer the question in my previous comment: are you importing `AppModule` in `main.ts` from a file that re-exports it instead of where it is defined (`app.module.ts`, I assume)?