# Angular 5 :ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular5

I am trying to build my angular5 application but got the following error 
on `ng build`.

I've tried the solution from this fix https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8798

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

But still, I am getting the error

`ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.`

**Versions**

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.3
Node: 9.9.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.2.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack   0.7.5
@angular-devkit/core            0.8.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      0.8.3
@angular/cli                    6.2.3
@schematics/angular             0.8.3
@schematics/update              0.8.3
rxjs                            5.5.7
typescript                      2.5.3
webpack                         4.19.1
```

**UPDATE**

main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: can you please post your main.ts and app module code? meanwhile this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685179/angular-2-no-ngmodule-metadata-found

Comment: @veben  not a new project this happened when i upgraded cli to 6

Comment: @PratapA.K updated question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50285039/2134604