# ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'HomeModule'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am getting the error mentioned in the title when running the Ionic CLI command `ionic cordova run android`.

What I tried to fix the problem:

Checked that `main.ts` file contains the following code

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Removed `node_modules` folder and ran `npm install`.

Reinstalle angular/cli with the commands posted [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48416871/5964318).

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SijaintiService } from '../app/sijainti.service';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule, 
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule' },
      { path: 'tiedot', loadChildren: './tiedot/tiedot.module#TiedotModule' }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    SijaintiService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

home.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomePage } from './home.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

Comment: Can you please add your AppModule and HomeModule code here? Or you can create a project at https://stackblitz.com/ and share the link.

Comment: I added the pieces of code to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Change **HomeModule** to **HomePageModule** in your route list, because your class name is HomePageModule.

Change this,

```
 { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule' },
```

to this,

```
 { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule' },
```

Comment: I have created a project for ionic 4 here, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ionic-4, Please fork the project, add your code and share the link.

Comment: There is no router issue in your project, The issue seems to be in the google native plugin. If you are using the old plugin version, consider using the latest version for ionic 4.  I have replicated the same code here and commented out the loadmap function, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ionic-4-4sglyn . As I said, there is no router issue in that project.

Comment: I am using `@ionic-native/google-maps 5.0.0.beta.26` for Ionic 4, but the plugin doesn't work. Are there any other alternatives on how to get the map working in Ionic 4 or do I need to downgrade?

Answer (score 1):

You are naming the module as `HomePageModule` and the error is `HomeModule` not defined. Could be a typo ?

You could either rename the export as

```
export class HomeModule {}
```

or modify the lazy loaded module as

```
{ path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule' }, // from HomeModule
```