# Angular 5: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'

Tags: angular

I have an existing project with angular 5 and I get this error when trying to serve the application with `ng-serve`
Here is the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "<=1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.3",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.0.1",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.16",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.23",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^6.14.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
```

I also have webpack 3.11 installed and I've searched many other workarounds but nothing helped.
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685179/angular-2-no-ngmodule-metadata-found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 : No NgModule metadata found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685179/angular-2-no-ngmodule-metadata-found)

Comment: Yeah, thanks but i tried all of these